# How do i know if my BundleProduct is still valid?

Tags: next.js, magento2

I have a client who has some bundleProducts in Magento 2. We fetch, create, update the cart via GraphQL via nextjs. I have the issue that someone can add a BundleProduct to his cart with product X and some other products. But sometimes the client wants to change the simpleProducts inside of the BundleProduct. So when a customer has the bundleProduct in his Cart with product X but product X disappears it returns an error when placing an order.

Is there no other elegant way of knowing when a bundleProduct is no longer valid for the current cart without placing an order?

I expect it to show an error before the checkout